# Convert Python or C# selenium test file to .side file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation, selenium-ide

I am trying to build additional functionality into Selenium IDE and would like the ability to import and run tests created outside of Selenium IDE using the browser extension. Is there any sort of converter or code that can take a Selenium test from something like Python or C# and convert it to a .SIDE file?

Comment: Just guessing, but I'm thinking this isn't likely - tests written in a programming language likely contain logic/code outside of what the Selenium IDE supports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, there is no easy way to covert from object oriented written Selenium tests to .side files. One could write a parser that converted just Selenium functions to .side xml code, but logic outside of the selenium package has no equivalent in a .side file.